# How to find a submatrix with largest sum in a Matrix

Tags: c++

Given a matrix with these elements:

```
4 2 7 11
3 8 19 1
11 12 7 5
19 14 4 7
```

Write a C++ code to find a 2x2 submatrix which has the largest sum.

in this case:

```
 11 12
 19 14
```

I have done something but it doesn't work:

```
  #include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int n,m;

    cout<<"Give M and N ";
    cin>>m>>n;
    int a[m][n];
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        cin>>a[i][j];
    }
    }
    int smax=0,suma,x,y,k,l,i,j;


    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++) 
            for(k=i;k<i+2;k++)
            for(l=j;l<j+2;l++) suma=suma+a[k][l];

    if(suma>smax) {smax=suma; x=i,y=j; }
    }

    for(int i=x;i<i+2;i++)
        for(int j=y;j<j+2;j++)
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
}
```

Comment: The code you provided is not compilable. Please provide the full code that you wrote so that we can test it.

Comment: First of all, note that you have to extract all 2x2 minors of the given matrix. The number of these minors surely depends on the matrix size. The general formula is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Minor_(linear_algebra)&action=edit&section=3), i.e. `number of l x k minors in m x n matrix = C(m,l)*C(n,k)`

Comment: So write a program to choose `l` different numbers from `1` to `m`, and also choose `k` different numbers from `1` to `n`. Build the associated minor and calculate its sum. The rest would be straightforward.

Comment: Code Formatted, in ur question please!

Comment: `suma` not (re-)initialized.

Comment: `if(suma>smax) {smax=suma; x=i,y=j; }` seems not in the correct scope.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected a lot of mistakes:

- Initialized variables correctly.
- Added a check to see if the current loop variables (`k` and `l`) under a given `i` and `j` forms a valid 2x2 matrix.
- Rewritten the main loop more cleanly.
- Added a check for the case when the input matrix is of size less than 2x2.
- Corrected the printing loop at the last. (`x+2` instead of `i+2`)

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int m, n;

    cout << "Give M and N - ";
    cin >> m >> n;

    int a[m][n];

    for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }


    int smax = -1, suma = -1, x = -1, y = -1;

    for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            suma = 0;
            if ( i + 1 >= m || j + 1 >= n )
            {
                // No 2x2 matrix exists for this i and j.
                continue;
            }

            for ( int k = i; k < i + 2; k++ )
            {
                for ( int l = j; l < j + 2; l++ )
                {
                    suma = suma + a[k][l];
                }
            }

            if ( suma > smax )
            {
                smax = suma;
                x = i, y = j;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << endl << x << " " << y << " "  << smax << endl;

    if ( x == -1 || y == -1 )
    {
        // No 2x2 matrix found!
        cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    for ( int i = x; i < x + 2; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = y; j < y + 2; j++ )
        {
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Jw8g3H)

**Note:** `int a[m][n];` is variable-length array and is forbidden in ISO C++ even though it might be supported by some compilers like GCC.
You can instead use a 2-D vector while keeping the rest of your code same as before:

```
vector<vector<int> > a ( m, vector<int> ( n ) );
```